Fix for anchor tag button takes up full width of image
my a.shop-now button takes up the full height of the image and that was not what I wanted.
HTML:

<div class="carousel-cell">
    <picture> ... </picture>
    <a class="shop-now" href="#"></a>   
</div>

CSS for .carousel-cell:
position: relative;
width: 100%;

CSS for a.shop-now:
bottom: 0;
display: block;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 130%;
padding: 13px 15px;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
width: auto;

I am not sure what was I missing here - the objective is to have the button being shown to the bottom of the image without overlaying it. Any pointers will be much appreciated, thanks!

To archive this you need to update the CSS.


.carousel-cell {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.shop-now {
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 130%;
  padding: 13px 15px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}
<div class="carousel-cell">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" />
    <a class="shop-now" href="#">shop now</a>   
</div>




Then just remove position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; from the button
